# Generate Map using list of list using stream in Java 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have the following domain classes `Trip` and `Employee`:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Trip {
    private Date startTime;
    private Date endTime;
    List<Employee> empList;
    
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String empId;
}
```

I have a list of `Trip` instances. And I want to create a map of type `Map<String,List<Trip>>` associating *id* of each *employee* `empId` with a list of *trips* using Stream API.

*Here's my attempt:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Stream<String>, List<Trip>> x = trips.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getEmpList()
            .stream().map(Employee::getEmpId)
        ));
}
```

How can I generate the map of the required type?

When the type of map is `Map<String,List<Trip>>` it gives me a compilation error:

```
Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch:
cannot convert from Map<Object,List<Trip>> to Map<String,List<Trip>>
```

Comment: i tried i got Map<Stream<String>,List<Trip>> but i want something like Map<String,List<Trip>>

Comment: `Map<Stream<String>, List<Trip>> empMap = trip.stream().collect(
   Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getEmployee().stream().map(EMPLOYEE::getempid)))`

Comment: I posted the code

Comment: Better, instead of image, compile the code and post the compilation error as a text. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,List<Trip>> to Map<String,List<Trip>>

Comment: Since you're using JDK 8, I've added a [Java 8 compliant solution](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/ybt)

Comment: As I've said in the answer, you can use a plain `class` instead of a record. To avoid dialing with the boilerplate code, sprinkle it with Lombok annotations, like you've done with your domain classes.

Answer (score 2):

To group the data by the property of a nested object and at the same time preserve a link to the enclosing object, you need to flatten the stream using an ***auxiliary object*** that would hold references to both *employee id* and enclosing `Trip` instance.

A Java 16 [`record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/records.html) would fit into this role perfectly well. If you're using an earlier JDK version, you can implement it a plain `class` (*a quick and dirty way would be to use* `Map.Entry`*, but it decreases the readability, because of the faceless methods* `getKey()` *and* `getValue()` *require more effort to reason about the code*). I will go with a `record`, because this option is the most convenient.

The following line is all we need (*the rest would be automatically generated by the compiler*):

```
public record TripEmployee(String empId, Trip trip) {}
```

The first step is to flatten the stream data and turn the `Stream<Trip>` into `Stream<TripEmployee>`. Since it's *one-to-many* transformation, we need to use `flatMap()` operation to turn each `Employee` instance into a `TripEmployee`.

And then we need to apply collect. In order to generate the resulting Map, we can make use of the collector [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) with collector [`mapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) as a *downstream*. In collector `mapping` always requires a *downstream collector* and this case we need to provide `toList()`.

```
List<Trip> trips = // initializing the list
        
Map<String, List<Trip>> empMap = trips.stream()
    .flatMap(trip -> trip.getEmpList().stream()
        .map(emp -> new TripEmployee(emp.getEmpId(), trip))
    )
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        TripEmployee::empId,
        Collectors.mapping(TripEmployee::trip,
            Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

[*A Java 8 compliant solution is available via this Link*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/ybt)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which Java version you are using but since you have mentioned Stream, I will assume Java 8 at least.

Second assumption, not sure why but looking at your code (using `groupingBy` ) you want the whole `List<Trip>` which you get against an `empId` in a `Map`.

To have the better understanding first look at this code (without `Stream`):

```
public Map<String, List<Trip>> doSomething(List<Trip> listTrip) {

    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Trip trip : listTrip) {
        employeeList.addAll(trip.getEmployee());
    }

    Map<String, List<Trip>> stringListMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
        stringListMap.put(employee.getEmpId(), listTrip);
    }
    return stringListMap;
}
```

You can see I pulled an `employeeList` first , reason being your use case. And now you can see how easy was to create a map out of it.
You may use `Set` instead of `List` if you're worried about the duplicates.

So with `StreamApi` above code could be:

```
   public Map<String, List<Trip>> doSomethingInStream(List<Trip> listTrip) {

        List<Employee> employeeList = listTrip.stream().flatMap(e -> e.getEmployee().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpId, employee -> listTrip));
    }
```

You can take care of duplicates while creating map as well, as:

```
public Map<String, List<Trip>> doSomething3(List<Trip> listTrip) {

    List<Employee> employeeList = listTrip.stream().flatMap(e -> e.getEmployee().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getEmpId, employee -> listTrip, (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue));
}
```

Like the first answer says, if you are Java 16+ using `record` will ease your task a lot in terms of model definition.

Comment: Yeah I am using java 8 and  trying to group whole List<Trip> which i get against the empid in a Map.

Comment: @Jha - hope the answer helps then.

Comment: @Jha : I noticed you accepted the answer but then unaccepted it, did it not work? Anything you're stuck at, let me know if I can help?

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8 stream**

You can use the below approach to get the desired results using stream function `groupingBy`.
*Since you have mentioned above to use java 8, so my solution is inclined to java 8 itself.*

**Logic:**

*Here,*

- First I have created an additional list of `EmployeeTripMapping` object
  with `Trip` data corresponding to the `empId` by iterating the
  `listOfTrips`.
- I have used `Collectors.groupingBy` on the `List<EmployeeTripMapping>`
  and grouped the data based on the `empId` and using `Collectors.mapping`
  collect the list of Trip corresponding to the empId.

**Few Suggestions:**

1. **Records in java 14 :** As I can see in your problem statement, you
   are using lombok
   annotations to create getters, setters and constructors, so instead of
   that we can replace our data classes
   with records. Records are immutable classes that require only the type
   and name of fields. We do not need to create constructor, getters,
   setters, override toString() methods, override hashcode and equals
   methods. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html)
2. **JavaTimeAPI in java 8:** Instead of Date, you can use LocalDateTime available in java time API in java 8. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

**Code:**

```
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Trip t1 = new Trip(LocalDateTime.of(2022,10,28,9,00,00),
                  LocalDateTime.of(2022,10,28,18,00,00),
                  Arrays.asList(new Employee("emp1","id1")));
        Trip t2 = new Trip(LocalDateTime.of(2021,10,28,9,00,00),
                  LocalDateTime.of(2021,10,28,18,00,00),
                  Arrays.asList(new Employee("emp1","id1")));
        Trip t3 = new Trip(LocalDateTime.of(2020,10,28,9,00,00),
                  LocalDateTime.of(2020,10,28,18,00,00),
                  Arrays.asList(new Employee("emp2","id2")));
        Trip t4 = new Trip(LocalDateTime.of(2019,10,28,9,00,00),
                  LocalDateTime.of(2019,10,28,18,00,00),
                  Arrays.asList(new Employee("emp2","id2")));

        List<Trip> listOfTrips = Arrays.asList(t1,t2,t3,t4);

        List<EmployeeTripMapping> empWithTripMapping = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfTrips.forEach(x -> x.getEmpList().forEach(y ->
                empWithTripMapping.add(new EmployeeTripMapping(y.getEmpId(),x))));

        Map<String,List<Trip>> employeeTripGrouping = empWithTripMapping.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EmployeeTripMapping::getEmpId,
                        Collectors.mapping(EmployeeTripMapping::getTrip,
                                                 Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println(employeeTripGrouping);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeTripMapping.java**

```
public class EmployeeTripMapping {

    private String empId;
    private Trip trip;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Output:**

```
{emp2=[Trip{startTime=2020-10-28T09:00, endTime=2020-10-28T18:00, empList=[Employee{empId='emp2', name='id2'}]}, Trip{startTime=2019-10-28T09:00, endTime=2019-10-28T18:00, empList=[Employee{empId='emp2', name='id2'}]}], 
 emp1=[Trip{startTime=2022-10-28T09:00, endTime=2022-10-28T18:00, empList=[Employee{empId='emp1', name='id1'}]}, Trip{startTime=2021-10-28T09:00, endTime=2021-10-28T18:00, empList=[Employee{empId='emp1', name='id1'}]}]}
```